# What is time complexity for nested map

Tags: java, big-o, computer-science

For the nested map like :

```
Map<String, Map<String, List<String>>> map = new HashMap<String, HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>>();
```

What would the time complexity be for its normal operation like put, remove, containsKey?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The time complexity would be the same as the time complexity of non-nested `HashMap`s.

Each lookup still takes average constant time.

To search for an inner value in the nested `Map` you need to perform two lookups - the first in the outer `Map`, and if a value was found in the outer `Map`, a second lookup in the inner `Map`. Since both lookup will take constant time, the total lookup time remains constant.

The same is true for `put`, `remove`, etc...

Comment: So, when doing like:
for(Entry<String, Map<String, List<String>>> staff : map.entrySet()) { for(Entry<String, List<String>> subject : staff.getValue().entrySet()) { for(String sessionTime : subject.getValue()) {
subject.getValue()
}

would it be O(n^3) cause there are three for loops?

Comment: @승기유 It depends on what's `n`. The complexity of iterating over all the Strings in all the List values of all the inner maps is a multiplication of the size of the outer map, the max size of the inner maps and the max size of the Lists. If any of these sizes can be bound by a constant, the total complexity will be less than n^3.